# Ticks showing only partially or not at all

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts, ticks

I have the following code:

```
    h[k_, x_, t_] = 
  Boole[x < t < x + k] Boole[x + k <= 1] + 
   Boole[x < t < 1 || 0 < t < x + k - 1] Boole[x + k > 1];

pl[k_, t_, ep_] := 
 Plot[h[k, x, t], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-ep, 1 + 0.4 ep}, {-ep, 1 + .4 ep}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, Ticks -> {{0, t, t - k, 1 + t - k, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

If I now say

```
GraphicsGrid[{{pl[.4, .3, 0], pl[.4, .8, 0]}}]
```

then I get

[image]

with only part of the ticks along the horizontal axis showing.

If I say

```
GraphicsGrid[{{pl[.4, .3, .1], pl[.4, .8, .1]}}]
```

then I get

[image]

with the ticks at the origin not showing.

How can I fix these flaws?

---

It has been suggested that I use `Frame` and `FrameTicks`. However, I do not want frames. Also, this does not work either:

```
ep = 0;
h[k_, x_, t_] = 
  Boole[x < t < x + k] Boole[x + k <= 1] + 
   Boole[x < t < 1 || 0 < t < x + k - 1] Boole[x + k > 1];

pl[k_, t_, ep_] := 
 Plot[h[k, x, t], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-ep, 1 + 0.4 ep}, {-ep, 1 + .4 ep}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{0, t, t - k, 1 + t - k, 1}, {0, 1}}]

GraphicsGrid[{{pl[.4, .3, 0], pl[.4, .8, 0]}}]
```

[image]

Some of the ticks are showing only partially.

I am wondering why `GraphicsGrid` cannot handle such simple tasks.

---

It has also been suggested that there may be a problem with my global plot options.  I do not think I have ever enabled any global plot options. Here are some possibly relevant Graphics Options for Global Preferences:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you use `Frame` and `FrameTicks` instead. These should be proplerly handled by `GraphicsGrid`

Comment: You can selectively hide edges of the frame to get them only on the left and bottom sides (something like `Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}}`. As for the clipping that is still present: what version are you using?

Comment: @LukasLang : I am using Version 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022).

Comment: On my machine (Win64+M13.1), your commands lead to plots with full tick labels. Do you have some kind of global plot options enabled?

Comment: @Oscillon : Thank you for your comment. I do not think I have ever enable any global plot options. I do not even know how to do that. Could you please tell me how to check that?

Comment: @Oscillon : I have now added to the post some possibly relevant Graphics Options for Global Preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found out that this behavior was caused by me changing the magnification globally. I changed it because the default font size for Mathematica 13.1 is too large.

Anyhow, this should not have caused the clipping of the ticks. So, this appears to be a Mathematica bug, and I have reported it to the Wolfram support as such.

---

**Update:** I have now received a response from Wolfram that this is indeed a known issue, to be resolved in a future version of Mathematica.

For now, using `ImagePadding` is suggested, which indeed helps, even with global magnification set at 0.8: The code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

h[k_, x_, t_] = 
  Boole[x < t < x + k] Boole[x + k <= 1] + 
   Boole[x < t < 1 || 0 < t < x + k - 1] Boole[x + k > 1];

pl[k_, t_, ep_] := 
 Plot[h[k, x, t], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-ep, 1 + 0.4 ep}, {0, 1 + .4 ep}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Ticks -> {{0, t, 0.3 - 0.4, t - k, 1 + t - k, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  ImagePadding -> 20]

GraphicsGrid[{{pl[.4, .3, 0], pl[.4, .8, 0]}}]
```

produces a desired image:

[image]